# Onchange inside onchange jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

Im having trouble having code onchange inside onchange event.

some works and some dont work due to that.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function() { // this is radio button
        if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
                 $("#text_container").after(price_option());
            };
        if ($("#rk").is(':checked')) {
               $("#price_container").remove();
               $("#licensenumber_c").css({"display": 'none'
           });
         };
    });

 $('#category_group').on('change', function() { // this is select options

    if ($(this).val() == 101) {
              $("#underKategory").css({"display": 'none'});
              $("#modelcontainer").remove();
              $(".toolimage").css({ "display": 'block'});

        $('.sellkop').on('change', function() { // this is radio button
            if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
                $("#licensenumber_c").css({"display": 'block'});
                $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'block' });
            } else {
                $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'none'});
            }
        });
    } else {
               $(".bilar").remove();
              $(".toolimage").css({ "display": 'none'});
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 102) {
                $(".houses_container").remove();
                $(".toolimage").css({"display": 'none'});
                $("#underKategory").css({"display": 'inline-block'});
                $("#modelcontainer").remove();
    }

    ///............many other values continue
 });
</script>
```

i know there is better way to manage this code and simplify it , how can i do it ?

EDIT:

what i want is :  if i select an option , then get values to that option, then under this category option there is radio buttons , then every check button i need to get some data displayed or removed

here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4s5rwce2/7/) there looks my problem by jumping from categories when i select buy or sell , so 
if i select category-->check buy -->then select others . i dont get same result as if i select directly cars ---> buy

Comment: It's almost always wrong to put one event handler binding inside another. Every time the first event fires, you'll add another event binding to the second element.

Comment: You should just set a variable in the first change handler, and read that variable in the second change handler.

Comment: Instead of binding a new event handler, you trigger the event instead: `$('.sellkop').trigger('change');`.

Comment: add another class to `.sellkop` each time it is changed, like .inactive and .active, and use event delegation to bind the change event `$(document).on('change', '.sellkop.active')`

Comment: besides, loading HTML from a string is almost always a sign of bad practice. Maybe have all HTML there, just hide it in case it is not needed.

Comment: you might also be interested in http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: Requirement are not clear to me. Its not a well written code, binding change event inside another change event. Just think how many times you will bind same handler. Use either off()/one() methods or move binding outside and trigger its change event like Terry explained.

Comment: @Terry can you change my fiddle and use trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never resorted to even two answers before (let alone three), but based on all the comments, and in a desire to keep things simple another solution is to data-drive the visibility of other items based on selections, using `data-` attributes to store the selectors on the options and radio buttons.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4s5rwce2/28/

e.g the HTML for the select becomes

```
<select name="category_group" id="category_group">
    <option value="0">choose category</option>
    <option value='101' id='cat101' data-show="#sellbuy,.cars,.toolimage,#licenscontainer">cars</option>
    <option value='102' id='cat102' data-show="#sellbuy,#underKategory">others</option>
</select>
```

and the radio buttons like this:

```
 <input id='rs' type='radio' class='radio sellkop' value='s' name='type' checked='checked' data-show="#price_container,.cars,.toolimage"/>
```

The code becomes *very* simple then, simply applying the filters specified in the selected items.

```
$(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function () { // this is radio button
    // Hide defaults
    $("#price_container,.cars,.toolimage").hide();

    // Show the items desired by the selected radio button
    $($(this).data("show")).show();
});

$('#category_group').on('change', function () { // this is select options
    // Get the various possible data options and decide what to show/hide based on those
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();

    // Get the selected option
    var $li = $('option[value='+ value+']', $this);

    // Hide all the defaults first
    $('#licenscontainer,.cars,.toolimage,.sell,#underKategory').hide();

    // Now show any desired elements
    $($li.data('show')).show();

    // Fire change event on the radio buttons to ensure they change
    $('.sellkop:checked').trigger('change');
});
```

This is a very generic solution that will allow very complex forms to turn on/off other elements as required. You can add data-hide attributes and do something similar for those too if required.

Comment: this answer looks simpler and looks good , however just one thing i noticed is this `id="underKategory"` should not appear in select cars because its not in data- . should i make it hidden in css ?

Comment: Please adjust HTML according to your needs. This is purely a guide on a simple way to solve similar hide/show problems in a flexible way :)

Comment: And don't forget to remove any `console.log` commands or they will break the page on IE :)

Comment: I dont understand why `#underKategory` is not in `data-show` of `cars` But it showed anyway ? it should not show.

Comment: it should probably have been `$('#licenscontainer,.cars,.toolimage,.sell,#underKategory').hide();` for the defaults. Example updated. As I said you need to understand and tweak this pattern to suit your needs :)

Comment: Looks working now :) , thanks so much , this method is best and never came to my mind :) . Thanks for your help i will go with this answer.

Comment: *Phew!* Glad we got their in the end. I don't normally spend this long on a question, but I hate leaving things unfinished :)

Comment: can you just show me how to  remove any console.log , because im not familiar with it, or just change fiddle with it , thanks

Comment: Already changed the fiddle... just delete those any lines in the code with `console.log`

Comment: Thank you. +1 to your question too.

Comment: I want disturb you now by my suggestion wich i asked now for 3 times :) . ` My reason to use functions with html is to dont show hidden divs in my form in the console firebug. i was thinking to insert them from js instead of make it hidden in front of the eyes of users ,as they can make it display block and they see it.`

Comment: @Karim Daraf: If a user wants to figure out your page HTML, they will still figure it out (e.g. by showing options and copying HTML). Why are you so worried about hiding such simple information?

Comment: Because , they can make it not hidden and the div appears and they fill it and send it fillded. I have found this option not just here in my code, in other places also. Sometimes when this filled div which was hidden can trigger something else wich i dont want, thats why i dont want give possibility to play by hidden divs. if you understand me or if you have experience with this. I have seen other sites they dont use hidden divs. i never seen hidden div, they just come.

Comment: I get it, but this should all be covered by your server-side logic. You should not process fields that you are not expecting for particular selections (event if they are sent via post). *If* this was an MVC website you would not even think of having multiple view models for this view. You would just validate the incoming post data based on selections.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This was an attempt to fix the existing style of coding. I have posted an alternate answer showing a far simpler method using hide/show only.**

A few problems.

- *If* you must nest handlers, simply turn them **off** before you turn them **on**. Otherwise you are adding them more than once and all the previously recorded ones will fire as well.
- Your HTML strings are invalid (missing closing `</div>`)
- You can simply use `hide()` and `show()` instead of all the css settings. You should use `css` styling for any specific element styling requirements (e.g. based on classes).
- You need to replace specific divs, rather than keep using `after`, or you progressively add more html. For now I have use `html` to replace the content of the `#text_container` div.

HTML in strings is a maintenance nightmare (as your example with missing `</div>` shows). Instead use templates to avoid the editing problems. I use dummy script blocks with `type="text/template"` to avoid the sort of problems you have found. That type means the browser simply ignores the templates.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4s5rwce2/17/

HTML (with templates)

```
<script id="saljkop">
    <div class='sex sell' id='sellbuy' >
        <label ><input id='rs' type='radio' class='radio sellkop' value='s' name='type' checked='checked'/> Sell </label>
        <label ><input id='rk' type='radio' class='radio sellkop' value='k' name='type'/>buy</label>
    </div>
</script>
<script id="price_option">
    <div class="container" id = "price_container">
        <div>
            <label><input  class="price_option" name="price_opt" value="1" type="radio"/> Fix </label>
            <label class="css-label"><input  class="price_option" name="price_opt" value="2" type="radio"/> offer </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script id="cars">
    <div class="cars" >
        <div id="licenscontainer" ><div id="licensenumber_c">
                <input id="licensenumber" placeholder="Registrer number" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
<div id="categories">
    <select name="category_group" id="category_group">
        <option value="0">choose category</option>
        <option value='101' id='cat101'>cars</option>
        <option value='102' id='cat102'>others</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="underKategory">sthis is subcategory</div>
<div id="toolimage1" class="toolimage">dddddd</div>
<div id="text_container" class="text_container">textttttt</div>
```

New jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function () { // this is radio button
    console.log('.sellkop change');
    if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
        $("#text_container").html($('#price_option').html());
    };
    if ($("#rk").is(':checked')) {
        $("#price_container").remove();
        $("#licensenumber_c").hide();
    };
});

$('#category_group').on('change', function () { // this is select options

    if ($(this).val() == 101) {
        $(".sell").remove();
        $("#categories").after($('#saljkop').html());
        $("#sellbuy").after($('#cars').html());
        $("#text_container").html($('#price_option').html());
        $("#underKategory").hide();
        $(".toolimage").show();

        $('.sellkop').off('change').on('change', function () { // this is radio button
            if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
                $("#licensenumber_c").show();
                $(".toolimage").show();
            } else {
                $(".toolimage").hide();
            }
        });

    } else {
        $(".cars").remove();
        $(".toolimage").hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 102) {
        $(".sell").remove();
        $("#categories").after($('#saljkop').html());
        $("#text_container").html($('#price_option').html());
        $(".toolimage").hide();
        $("#underKategory").show();
    }

    ///............many other values continue
});
```

**Now if you prefer to not nest handlers (recommended), just add to your existing *delegated event handler* for the radio buttons:**

```
$(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function () { // this is radio button
    console.log('.sellkop change');
    if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
        $("#text_container").html($('#price_option').html());
        $("#licensenumber_c").show();
        $(".toolimage").show();
    };
    if ($("#rk").is(':checked')) {
        $("#price_container").remove();
        $("#licensenumber_c").hide();
        $(".toolimage").hide();
    };
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4s5rwce2/20/

Comment: not running good your fiddle. 1- select cars--> dont get radio buttons till you check buy and sell again. 2- when you select cars and then check buy and then jump to select others you lose the sell buy radio buttons.

Comment: @Karim Daraf: That was just an example to fix the first few problems. Can you please clarify the exact desired behaviour?

Comment: From your fiddle :1- select Cars --> (you must get fix radio buttons) 2- Select Cars---> check buy --->select others -->(you must get sell buy radio buttons.) . i need to dont loose what i have checked when i select other option.

Comment: @Karim Daraf: Updated solution above. I am still not 100% sure of the expected behaviour, but this should provide a better starting point for you.

Comment: 1- select cars-->check buy--->select others--->(buy radio must stay checked with its contents)

Comment: @Karim Daraf: Then you should not keep adding content dynamically and only hide/show elements. I would suggest simplifying the whole thing to already include all options and forget the dynamic adding (which does not appear to be needed).

Comment: My reason to use functions with html is to dont show hidden divs in my form in the console. i was thinking to insert them from js instead of make it hidden in the eyes of users.

Comment: @ Karim Daraf: If someone wants to see it, than can always look at the code. Just hide/show elements. Second answer added with that approach. The radio values are now retained. Much simpler code and HTML now.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This was a second answer, hoping to simplify the overall problem to one of hiding/showing existing elements. I have posted a third(!) answer that takes it to an even simpler scenario using `data-` attributes to provide the filter selections.**

I am adding a second answer as this is a complete re-write. The other answer tried to fix *the existing way of adding elements dynamically*. I now think that was simply a bad approach.

The basic principal with this one is to have very simple HTML with the required elements all present and simply hide/show the ones you need/ Then the selected values are retained:

This uses the multi-structure to effectively hide.show the licence field based on two separate conditions.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4s5rwce2/23/

Html (all element s present, just the ones you do not need hidden):

```
<div id="categories">
    <select name="category_group" id="category_group">
        <option value="0">choose category</option>
        <option value='101' id='cat101'>cars</option>
        <option value='102' id='cat102'>others</option>
    </select>
    <div class='sex sell' id='sellbuy' style="display: none">
        <label>
            <input id='rs' type='radio' class='radio sellkop' value='s' name='type' checked='checked' />Sell</label>
        <label>
            <input id='rk' type='radio' class='radio sellkop' value='k' name='type' />buy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cars" style="display: none">
        <div id="licenscontainer">
            <div id="licensenumber_c">
                <input id="licensenumber" placeholder="Registrer number" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="underKategory">sthis is subcategory</div>
<div id="toolimage1" class="toolimage">dddddd</div>
<div id="text_container" class="text_container">
    <div class="container" id="price_container" style="display: none">
        <div>
            <label>
                <input class="price_option" name="price_opt" value="1" type="radio" />Fix</label>
            <label class="css-label">
                <input class="price_option" name="price_opt" value="2" type="radio" />offer</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.sellkop', function () { // this is radio button
    if ($("#rs").is(':checked')) {
        $("#price_container").show();
        $(".cars").show();
        $(".toolimage").show();
    };
    if ($("#rk").is(':checked')) {
        $("#price_container").hide();
        $(".cars").hide();
        $(".toolimage").hide();
    };
});

$('#category_group').on('change', function () { // this is select options

    if ($(this).val() == 101) {
        $(".sell").hide();
        $("#sellbuy").show();
        $(".cars").show();
        $("#underKategory").hide();
        $(".toolimage").show();
        $('#licenscontainer').show();
    } else {
        $('#licenscontainer').hide();
        $(".cars").hide();
        $(".toolimage").hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 102) {
        $(".sell").hide();
        $("#sellbuy").show();
        $(".toolimage").hide();
        $("#underKategory").show();
        $(".cars").hide();
    }
    $("#price_container").toggle($("#rs").is(':checked'));
    ///............many other values continue
});
```

Comment: i have seen your fiddle 21 . you used  $("#licensenumber_c").hide(); and show but they dont appear to work . But it was almost near .

Comment: Still looking at the last changes. As all the ids/variables are not English it is not easy, I have to keep checking everything twice :)

Comment: Not perfect (some duplicate code not needed), but hopefully does what you wanted.

Comment: hahaha i found also one thing. 1: select cars-->check buy-->select others-->select cars (you should not lose radio buttons of fix)

Comment: @Karim Daraf: I think you get the idea now and can probably change the logic to suit your needs :) I suggest simplifying the naming and divs so that it is clear what needs to be hidden/shown. I would have done that but I would have had to change all the names to English so they would have meaning to me.  (*If not my hourly rate is £60 GBP* :>)

Comment: I preciate your help aussie, my main problem is that i loose things from  selecting other options as i said in my question and it still in your fiddle. what about my question this : My reason to use functions with html is to dont show hidden divs in my form in the console. i was thinking to insert them from js instead of make it hidden in the eyes of users.  other thing is i have many select options not just 101 and 102 , so this code must not be closed just to this i used  in my fiddle.

Comment: Adding options dynamically is a lot more trouble than hiding/showing. If there are many more options, it is best you show an example of them all so that I can offer a better third solution (probably data-driven instead using `data-` attributes to turn on/off the other options).

Comment: the problem is just in this option of select and radio , i dont want data looses when i change select option . if its sell and select other option then it comes with sell divs. if its buy and change select option then i must get it with buy divs in other select.